# JavaScript problem while installing NetBeans and JDK in OS X 10.5.8 - Leopard

Tags: java, leopard, javascript

I downloaded the newest version of NetBeans and JDK and wanted to install it on my MacBook that runs on OS X 10.5.8 but I couldn't.
This is the screenshot I made :
[image]

Maybe since the this OS X version is quite old I will be pushed to install some older version of NetBeans...

Anyway, why does it say I have a problem with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out I want to install the 64 bit version of NetBeans but I have 32 bit OS X....  So, that can be the reason...